# update-alternatives arguments - <link> and <path> can't be the same

Tags: command-line, debian, symbolic-link, default-programs, update-alternatives

I want to add `vimb` to the default browsers in `x-www-browser`. I don't see it in `update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`, so I think I have to `--install` it. After some time spent in reading `man update-alternatives` and searching, I came up with this:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/vimb x-www-browser /usr/local/bin/vimb 30
```

It seems stupid (the repeating arguments), but I think I haven't understood the manual correctly. What exactly do I have to pass at `link` and `path`?

```
COMMANDS
   --install link name path priority [--slave link name path]...

    link is the generic name for the master link,
    name is the name of its symlink in the alternatives directory, and
    path  is  the  alternative  being introduced for the master link.

TERMINOLOGY
   alternatives directory
          A directory, by default /etc/alternatives, containing the symlinks.

   alternative name
          The name of a symbolic link in the alternatives directory.

   alternative (or alternative path)
          The name of a specific file in the filesystem, which may be made accessible  via
          a generic name using the alternatives system.
```

Do I have to make a copy of `/usr/local/bin/vimb` in `/etc/alternatives` or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manpage is somewhat confusing IMHO, but the key parts seem to be

```
--install link name path priority [--slave link name path]...
       Add a group of alternatives to the system.  link is the  generic
       name for the master link, name is the name of its symlink in the
       alternatives directory, and path is the alternative being intro‐
       duced  for the master link.
```

where `generic name` is described in the `TERMINOLOGY` section as

```
generic name (or alternative link)
       A name, like /usr/bin/editor, which refers, via the alternatives
       system, to one of a number of files of similar function.
```

whereas the actual executable target is referred to as the `path`

```
alternative (or alternative path)
       The name of a specific file in the filesystem, which may be made
       accessible via a generic name using the alternatives system.
```

so in your case it needs to be

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /usr/local/bin/vimb 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Some experiments showed me the correct combination of the arguments. It turned out that `link` had to be `/usr/bin/x-www-browser`, so finally the command becomes:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /usr/local/bin/vimb 30
```

I don't understand yet why `update-alternatives` needs both `/usr/bin/x-www-browser` and `x-www-browser`.
`where x-www-browser` returns the former, which means that both point to the same location. Anyway, this is a working solution, but I'd still be happy to see an answer from someone with a deeper understanding of how things work.